# PyQt: How to change currentIndex in QComboBox when custom QAbstractListModel data changed

Tags: python, qt, model-view-controller, pyqt, qcombobox

I've read some examples on how to define a custom model for a `QComboBox` widget.

Here's how I defined my model:

```
class LevelListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, *args):
        """ datain: a list where each item is a row
        """
        QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.levelList = []
    def rowCount(self, parent=QModelIndex()):
        return len(self.levelList)

    def data(self, index, role):
        if index.isValid() and role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            return QVariant(index.row())
        else:
            return QVariant()
    def addLevel(self,level):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self.levelList.append(level)
        self.endResetModel()
```

I set the model to my `QComboBox`:

```
self.levelListModel = LevelListModel()
self.ui.levelComboBox.setModel(self.levelListModel)
```

I add a model to my list this way:

```
newLevel = Level (self.levelListModel.rowCount() + 1)
self.levelListModel.addLevel(newLevel)
```

The item is added correctly and I can see it inside the combobox, but I would like to change the currentIndex to be the new item's index.

I guess `QAbstractListModel` could raise some kind of events that `QComboBox` can listen to, but I haven't still found how to do that.

My questions are:

1. How can I notify the `QComboBox` that model data changed, and listen to that event to modify currentIndex accordingly?
2. I used `[begin|end]ResetModel` because my entry should be an ordered sequence of integer. So I need to rebuild the data list completely once an item in the middle of the list have been removed. I don't know if this is the right way to go. Any better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1**

> How can I notify the QComboBox that model data changed, and listen to
>   that event to modify currentIndex accordingly?

No need to listen an event from the way you do things. You *know* when the model data is changed, because you add things yourself. Just change the `currentIndex` after adding a data.

I'd probably modify the `addLevel` method to return the `QModelIndex` of the added item and then use it to set the `currentIndex` of the `QComboBox`:

```
class LevelListModel(QAbstractListModel):
    # [skipped]
    def addLevel(self,level):
        self.beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), len(self.levelList), len(self.levelList))
        self.levelList.append(level)
        self.endInsertRows()
        return self.index(len(self.levelList)-1)
```

and

```
newLevel = Level (self.levelListModel.rowCount() + 1)
newIndex = self.levelListModel.addLevel(newLevel)
self.ui.levelComboBox.setCurrentIndex(newIndex)
```

**2**

> I used [begin|end]ResetModel because my entry should be an ordered
>   sequence of integer. So I need to rebuild the data list completely
>   once an item in the middle of the list have been removed. I don't know
>   if this is the right way to go. Any better solution?

That depends. `[begin|end]ResetModel` is for really drastic changes. I don't see how keeping an ordered list of integers would lead to such changes for single item addition/removal. From what you describe, you should be using `[begin|end]InsertRows` and `[begin|end]RemoveRows`.